# Issue with python import for mapr_streams_python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, stream, mapr

I'm playing with the MapR Sandbox and would like to import some data in MapR stream using python. But I'm having an importing issue and I dont know why. I followed instructions from MApR website (see reference at the end of this post) and looked everywhere for a clue, but know I don't really know what else I can do. I tried with python 2.7 and python 3.6.

```
File "producer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mapr_streams_python import Producer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mapr_streams_python'
```

I have installed it globally like doc is telling me to do, the file is located in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages for python 2  /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages for python 3

Someone has an idea?

Thank you

**References**

https://mapr.com/docs/60/AdvancedInstallation/InstallingStreamsPYClient.html

https://mapr.com/docs/52/MapR_Streams/MapRStreamsPythonExample.html

Comment: Did you install the module via `pip`? To list all the modules available try running `pip list` in command prompt to see the list of modules installed and validate if the required module is installed successfully.

Comment: I just checked, my module is there

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the folder for the module was incorrectly named in the folder that it was installed at. After getting to the directory with the modules (/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages), just run this command:

```
cp -R mapr_streams_python-0.11.0-py3.6.egg-info/ mapr_streams_python
```

You should then be able to import the package in python.